# Java - vector de tuplas

Tags: java, array, vectores

Quiero tratar de definir un vector que sea de la siguiente forma:
`[ [10,0] [3,2] [9,6] ...[a,b] ]`

- a y b serán números enteros.
- Elemento de lista

Cada tupla[a,b] representa una estación.

Es correcto así?

```
new int[][] { {7,0}, {8,2}, {9,5}, {3,1} }
```

Y si quisiera una inicializada a 0?

Una vez creado, cómo se accede a cada tupla completa [a,b]?
Cómo se accede a cada cada valor de una tupla 'a' o 'b'?

Perdón si es muy básica la duda, pero no consigo ver la forma de hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: new int[filas][columnas] ={ {7,0}, {8,2}, {9,5}, {3,1} }; esto es una matriz , array de arrays o vector de vectores para acceder a cualquier datos necesitas saber la posicion en la que se encuentra el dato requerido,si quieres acceder  al numero 3,seria int[3][1] por que tu matriz tiene 4 filas y 2 columnas (los indices parten de 0),frecuentemente usarias dos ciclos for para acceder a los datos que quieres ,ahora si declarass una matriz int [3][2] solo podras ingresar 3 filas y dos columnas esto no aumenta ni disminuye,si buscas algo que haga eso,lo mas recomendable es que uses un arraylist

Comment: @Dramaturgo, muchas gracias por la información! Estoy resolviendo un ejercicio y debe ser un array de arrays. Imagino que pueden haber alternativas más sencillas, pero mis bajos conocimientos no me ayudan tampoco. Probaré como dices!

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad, sería una clase, donde tengas tus tuplas con valor a, b y otros valores que te pudieran surgir y todas estas en una lista de objetos de la clase tuplas.

```
public class tuplas{
  int a;
  int b;

  public tuplas(int _a, int _b){
       a = _a;
       b = _b;
   }

  public int getA(){
     return a;
  }
  public int getB(){
     return b;
  }


}
```

Y para gestionarlas:

```
List<tuplas> mis_tuplas = new ArrayList<tuplas>();

tuplas tupla1 = new tuplas(1,2);
mis_tuplas.add(tupla1);
   
int A_tupla0 = mis_tuplas.get(0).getA();
int B_tupla0 = mis_tuplas.get(0).getB();
```